# Clicking a button(with no id) using mshtml in wpf web browser

Tags: wpf, browser, mshtml

I'm trying to fill a WPF WebBrowser page using mshtml. But, I'm not able to find out the id of the button from the html. How can I find the ID? Or is there is any alternative to submit the form?

Code:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)browser.Document;

try
{     
    ((mshtml.HTMLInputElement)doc.all.item("?????")).click();
}
```

Html page (Continue is the button text):

```
<li><a href="/uas/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=3c708034-081f-4aca-b61c-f6518a1e0f8c&amp;trk=uas-continue" class="btn-primary">Continue</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WebBrowser` control in `WPF` is different from the one in `WinForm`.

The System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control has a Document property, which gets the Document object that represents the hosted HTML page.

You need to cast this Document object to COM interface `IHTMLDocument2` and then access the all property on the document to get each element in the HTML document.

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
doc.all.item("link")).click();
```

Please refer to the MSDN article:
[Handling HTML Element Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508508%28VS.85%29.aspx#get_all)

A similar post here: [Accessing DOM from WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950413/accessing-dom-from-webbrowser)