# Accessing DOM from WebBrowser

Tags: c#, dom, browser, pixelsense

I am trying to implement a browser-like little application that would allow me to modify the viewed web-sites appearance (e.g. make the font for links bigger). It is designed for Microsoft Surface, to be used on a huge touchscreen. It uses WPF for the UI.

I am intending to use a WebBrowser control for this task. However there are two classes called WebBrowser in the docs. One of them is in `System.Windows.Forms`, the other in `System.Windows.Controls`. The first one gives access to DOM model, but is intended for Forms applications (if I understand correctly, that's definitely not what I have). The second one is added by default if you add the controller in xaml, but it gives no access to the DOM.

So, how do I access the DOM model from a WebBrowser for Surface? I am very new to c# and Microsoft technologies, so I apologise if my question is unclear or obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` class you can use the Document property. 
Add [mshtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference to your project that should be available by right click on project and selecting Add Reference, then you should be able to cast it to mshtml.IHTMLDocument2

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
// do something like find button and click
htmlDoc.all.item("testBtn").click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! A quick question - where I should have found that information? As I couldn't find that anywhere...

Comment: Would I be able to read dynamic dom ? i mean if the page inside the webbrowser build a html dynamic using ajax , will I be able to read it ?

Comment: it should be `webBrowser.Document.DomDocument`

Comment: @Ahmad this answer is related to Controls.WebBrowser, not Forms.WebBrowser

Comment: I have a webbrowser, and i need one next click, it works fine, then on the next form on the same url, i need username/pwd and a login button click. Is it possible to do this with hand from code? Eg. from WebBrowser_LoadCompleted event? First click fine, the ui ok, but navigating not comes in WPF and no events happening...