# webclient htmlagility pack web parsing

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, html-agility-pack

C# + webclient + htmlagility pack + web parsing

I wanted to go through the list of the jobs of this [page](http://jobboerse.arbeitsagentur.de/vamJB/stellenangeboteFinden.html?execution=e2s1&d_6827794_p=1) but i can't parse those links because it changes.

One of the example, when i see the link as it is in the browser([Link](http://jobboerse.arbeitsagentur.de/vamJB/stellenangeboteFinden.html?execution=e2s1&_eventId_detailView&benc=rkkZ/boyLiG9h28kCpzHxfVYJyT2P1c9GVClecgXT3fxzGbNWsoChQ==&benc=afJ0OkffR3PRR9JFaY55SyIcKND4x2DKGIXSTgcjmcRu3Insgz5lxLL8kcY5ojGs%2bjXGJ7k9Nok=&benc=eQ0SRj9kvsEhY9j6dJ0PJ2fAoInOxfyvwq2vTiAeEqpoNnI4pX5o/1dFdb2ldrAE3O6Dx0toq6RbS%2bInhnXdQtVviC1umx9lgkBXPoaTvbFvdOPiCbPL/zBwHnXc4%2bSbHaoOwWhGlAn09gnO8DpSBYfg0yECjFpca/mmdi1pYK40Yfvf29H/VSpZjTX1w8ql)),,

when i parse it using webclient and htmlagilitypack i get the changed link

Do i have to do settings on webclient? to include sessions or scripts?

Here is my code on that..

```
private void getLinks()
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("categories.txt");
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string url = sr.ReadLine();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string source = wc.DownloadString(url);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(source);
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='internerLink primaerElement']");
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("http://jobboerse.arbeitsagentur.de" + node.Attributes["href"].Value);

        }
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you clarify how HtmlAgilityPack is related to your problem?

Comment: I am actually parsing the page and getting links just like the example above (the longer one). But the parsing get links which is totally different as shown when I do "inspect element" on chrome. Instead of the above example, i get links which contains "session id="..

Comment: I don't see a sessionId in my View Source, but then again, I'm not logged in. Does it matter? Why is it important you get the session Id?

Comment: Chances are that some of the links are generated by JavaScript. That script runs only inside of a browser. WebClient can't retrieve them because they do not exist.

Comment: yes, its about javascript thingy,,but how can i parse the page getting those links that i think generated by javascript. Is there any way if webclient cannot retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You may try a WebBrowser class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then use its DOM [Accessing DOM from WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950413/accessing-dom-from-webbrowser) to retrieve the links.

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
// do something like find button and click
htmlDoc.all.item("testBtn").click();
```