# How to invoke onchange, onblur events of a DOM element inside WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, ihtmldocument2, microsoft.mshtml

I've tried a lot to find a solution of invoking DOM events of the loaded document of WPF WebBrowser. Here's a code to invoke click event-

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
htmlDoc.all.item("testBtn").click();
```

Ref: [Accessing DOM from WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950413/accessing-dom-from-webbrowser/12963485#12963485)

But onchange, onblur events are a bit different and do not work in this way. I found another solution- i.e. hosting WinForm WebBrowser control into WPF window, because it is possible in that control. If there's a way to do it on WPF WebBrowser then why will I go for a workaround! So is there any solution?