# How to set text to an input in WebBrowser control using C# in Desktop Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm working on a desktop application in VS using C#, the application contains a button for loading a file of two columns, and an area  to load a webpage.. So, the purpose is I want to put the first column in a specific input and the second column to a different input of the webpage, and click a button in the webpage.

Any ideas

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing DOM from WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950413/accessing-dom-from-webbrowser)

Comment: @NineBerry, no it;s not

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to set the values :

```
HtmlElement button = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnC");
button.InvokeMember("click");

HtmlElement txt = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txt1");
txt.SetAttribute("value","this is just an example");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample source code. Add error handling where necessary.

In order to use the IHTML* interfaces, add a reference to the Microsoft HTML Object library to the project.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string documentSource = @"
        <html>
        <body>
        <form action=""https://www.google.com/search"">
            <input name=""q"" id=""searchInput""/>
            <input type=""submit"" id=""searchButton""/> 
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
    ";

    // navigate to document
    webBrowser1.Navigate("about:" + documentSource);

    // Wait until the document is fully loaded
    // Instead of using this loop, use "DocumentCompleted" event of the Webbrowser in
    // production code
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState < WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    // Get IHTMLDocument reference
    IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;

    // Get searchInput and set value
    var searchInput = document.all.item("searchInput") as IHTMLInputElement;
    searchInput.value = "Hello";

    // Get searchButton and call click
    var searchButton = document.all.item("searchButton") as IHTMLElement;
    searchButton.click();
}
```