# Unable to access the DOM using WPF WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, mshtml

I am using the following code to get to the DOM of the web page. I am using the WPF WebBrowser component (not the WinForms one which works fine according to some posts). But with the WPF WebBrowser component, there is no way that I can figure it out. I am referencing mshtml assembly and according to some posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950413/accessing-dom-from-webbrowser) I should have access to the DOM. But when I hover over the doc variable during debug, it displays a value of "System._ComObject" which is confusing. My goal is to highlight the search words in the DOM but cannot get access to it.

```
            IHTMLDocument2 doc = WebBrowserComponent.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
            if (doc != null)
            {
                StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(doc.body.outerHTML);

                var words = SearchWords;
                foreach (String key in words)
                {
                    String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>" + key + "</span>";
                    html.Replace(key, substitution);
                }
                doc.body.innerHTML = html.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: You should cast `Document` property to correct COM interface or use `InvokeScript` method

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Isn't that what I am already doing in my code? I'm casting it to IHTMLDocument2. Otherwise I need more details on your suggestion. Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I add a button to highlight the items refer to your code:
Code for XAML:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="HightLight" Click="Button_Click"> </Button>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Source="https://www.bing.com/" Width="800" Height="380"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The cs code is:

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc = webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
        if (doc != null)
        {
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(doc.body.outerHTML);
            dynamic document = webBrowser.Document;
            string str =  document.getElementById("sb_form_q").value;
            var words = new[] { str,"Bing" };
            foreach (String key in words)
            {
                String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>" + key + "</span>";
                html.Replace(key, substitution);
            }
            doc.body.innerHTML = html.ToString();
            document.getElementById("sb_form_q").value = str;
        }
    }
```

And the result picture is below:
[image]
I can't reproduce the error, could you tell me which step that I missed?