# Fit html page width in WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, webbrowser-control

I have a lot of local html pages which I open in a WebBrowser control in my app.
I would like the page to initially open to **fit the width** of the control and ideally to change its width to fit the control after a user resize.
As there are a lot of pages, I would prefer a c#, js or css solution which doesn't require modifying the html files.
I searched high and low, tried tens of solutions (many of them here on SO) but nothing seems to work.
Win 7, IE 11, VS 2022
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Win7 and IE11, I have a hunch you're using WinForms.  The DOM can be accessed through the WebBrowser control's Document property where we can add the CSS.  Put this in your `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event handler:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style += ";width:100%;";
```

The Style property is just like an HTML `style=` attribute, that is, a string of CSS styles separated by semicolons.  The appended string starts with a semicolon in case the existing styles don't end with one.

For WPF, first see [Accessing DOM from WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950413/accessing-dom-from-webbrowser).  Then you can put this in your `WebBrowser.LoadCompleted` event handler:

```
var document = webBrowser1.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
document.body.style.width = '100%';
```

Comment: @Scolo Thank you for your answer. It solved the initial load problem. I couldn't verify it though for the case when the user resizes the form (my form includes 3 WebBrowser controls and I still can't cause the one I'm interested in resize when the user resizes the form.

Comment: @alexb Are you updating the WebBrowser control's size when its container resizes or have it docked?